# How can I supply two arbitrary number of arguments to a lambda expression in python?

Tags: python, lambda

Edit: I'm sorry for the bad title. Not sure how to describe this easily.

So I have two functions which are incredibly similar, let's call them `foo` and `bar`:

```
def foo(x,y):
  return lambda a,b: (x+a, y+b)
```

or equivalently

```
lambda x,y: lambda a,b: (x+a, y+b)
```

as well as

```
def bar(x,y,z):
  return lambda a,b,c: (x+a, y+b, z+c)
```

or equivalently

```
lambda x,y,z: lambda a,b,c: (x+a, y+b, z+c)
```

Can I generalize this? I want to pass in a list of arguments of any length and get a lambda back that takes an argument of that same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*args` and generalize:

```
lambda *outer: lambda *inner: tuple(a + b for a, b in zip(outer, inner))
```

Or:

```
lambda *outer: lambda *inner: tuple(map(sum, zip(outer, inner)))
```

If a list suffices, then the `tuple()` can be replaced with a list comprehension (`[a + b for ...]`) or replaced with `list()` in the second version (Python 3) or just removed altogether (Python 2).

Demo:

```
>>> outer = lambda *outer: lambda *inner: tuple(a + b for a, b in zip(outer, inner))
>>> inner = func(1, 2, 3)
>>> inner(2, 3, 4)
(3, 5, 7)
>>> inner = outer(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> inner(4, 5, 6, 7)
(5, 7, 9, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `*args` notation:

```
def bar(*args1):
  return lambda *args2: tuple(map(sum,zip(args1,args2)))
```

Comment: Just a tiny comment: `map` returns a list, not a tuple. May not be that important, though.